# Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch

Tags: authentication, debian

Once Debian booted up and able to login(put username and password) ..but the cursor shows watch..means waiting for something..switch to vc like Atl-ctrl-f1 and tail to /var/log/xorg.0.log saying that it is suspending AIGLX clinets for VT switch?

How to resolve this problem?

Am running Debian Squeeze.

TIA

Bhaskar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VT switch is what you did with C-M-F1 and probably unrelated to your problem.

Check that your hard drive isn't full. Especially /var/log/.

Try running "xinit /usr/bin/X11/xterm -- :1" as a user.
If that doesn't work, try "sudo Xorg".

Answer (score 1):

Boot linux in usb, an replace var folder, delete one on system an put var folder from your usb.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`